# Button and click display

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, click

I have tried Everything to my knowledge and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

public class activity_main extends Activity {

    TextView txtCount;
    Button btnCount;
    int count=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtCount= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        btnCount= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                count++;
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
        });

    }
}

}
```

No errors appear at any point and the program works without errors; the button clicks and does not crash, but no click is counted numerically in the textView.

Comment: try log your variable `count` to see if it increase

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked" + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

Comment: why you dont do it in the mainactivity class instead of declare a new class

Comment: @sean is right, you are missing `Override` anotation on onClick().

Comment: let me know if my solution helped

Comment: I used your answer but no result, click counts are still not shown in the textview. no errors appear either in the code or when the app runs. the @override makes sense, ty all for pointing that out!

Comment: Just try like this ""+count

Comment: rofl so it turns out                                                                                      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
was the error. when i deleted that code all of your edits worked amazingly. ty so much for your help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you onClick() listener is wrong.** 
try this one

```
btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                   count++;
                                   txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                                }
                            });
```